# Else/If Loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I'm really novice to all of this, and I'm learning it in class. My assignment is to write an Else/If Loop where we display 1-100. If the integer is divisible by 3 display "play", if divisible by 4 display "ball", and if divisible by 3 and 4 display "Play Ball", anything else is just the integer. 
I have my code working here, but I can't get my 3 and 4 to display "Play Ball", unless I run it by itself. Hope that makes sense, here's what I have:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Play');
  } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Ball');
  } else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Play Ball');
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your AND condition first!

Comment: Fizz-Buzz strikes again!

Comment: Note the order of your conditions. If i % 3, we log 'Play' and we're done. If i % 4, we log 'Ball' and we're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move this`i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0` condition to the top:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Play Ball');
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Play');
  } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Ball');
  } else  {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first if statement will always be true when the third statement (with the &&) will be true, you'll never make it to the third statement.  Try reordering as such:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

      if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
        console.log('Play Ball');
      } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
        console.log('Ball');
      } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log('Play');
      } else {
        console.log(i);
      }

}
```

Comment: They need 'Play ball' when the number is divisible by both 3 & 4!

Answer (score 0):

> 3 and 4 display

Above statement means, when **BOTH** condition satisfies then only you need to perform some task. In this scenario you need to use `&&`

```
   if ( (i % 3 === 0) && (i % 4 === 0) ) {
    console.log('Play Ball');
  }
```

**When to use `else` and/or `else if`**

Let's take an example, you have a number, which is not divisible by 3 and 4 and you are not concern about that number. Then, you simply use `else` to fall all those category into it.

Now, there is another scenario, when you have entered number, which is again not divisible by 3 and 4. But, you might want see, if it is only divisible by 3 or 4. Then, you use `else if` where you can put the condition to check.

```
   if ( (i % 3 === 0) && (i % 4 === 0) ) {
    console.log('Play Ball');
  }
   else if ( i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Play');
  }
   else if ( i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Ball');
  }
```

Comment: @downvoter I will definitely try to improve my answer, if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the check for divisible by both 3 and 4 to the top:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
     console.log('Play Ball');
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
     console.log('Play');
  } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
    console.log('Ball');
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```